# Methods are not returning the value I want

Tags: java

This method is the find the square root of the double argument entered. Its output is the same as the argument.

```
public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static String calculateSqaureRoot(double radicand){
        Math.sqrt(radicand);
        NumberFormat DecimalLimter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        DecimalLimter.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);

        return DecimalLimter.format(radicand);
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(calculateSqaureRoot(4.00));

            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you think `Math.sqrt(radicand);` does?

Comment: Please also pay attention to the names of your variables. `DecimalLimter.format(radicand);` - that looks like you calling a static method defined in the class `DecimalLimter`.

Answer (score 3):

You're ignoring the return value.  Change

```
Math.sqrt(radicand);
```

to

```
radicand = Math.sqrt(radicand);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign back the result of the sqrt operation. So it should be:

```
radicand = Math.sqrt(radicand);
```

As the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) tells:

> **Returns** the correctly rounded positive square root of a double value.

Comment: Better to assign it to a new variable.  After you've taken the square root, it's not the radicand any more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the simple explanation.